# how to get column values along with aggregated value (MAX)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I use `postgresql` as my storage engine.

I have a self-foreign-key reference of employee to manager.

Here is how my `employee` table looks:

```
employee_id   firstname  lastname   manager_id
11;           "Chuck";   "Norris";  NULL
1;            "Sergey";  "Brin";    11
3;            "Larry";   "Page";    11
5;            "Bill";    "Gates";   4
4;            "Father";  "Bill";    NULL
```

Now I want a query to display the (manager_id and count) of employee who has most employees under him/her.

That is for the above table, I expect

```
    id   max_count
    11        2
```

This query works;

```
select MAX(y.count) as max_count FROM
(select m.manager_id as id, count(m.manager_id) as count from employee m GROUP BY (id) ) y;

max_count
    2
```

But this does not work -- I just included the id column.

```
select y.id, MAX(y.count) as max_count FROM
(select m.manager_id as id, count(m.manager_id) as count from employee m GROUP BY (id) ) y;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "y.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select y.id, MAX(y.count) as max_count FROM
               ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "y.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803

Character: 8
```

Why this does not work?

Comment: 1. Can the hierarchy cascade to a depth > 1? Would you want to count recursively? 2. What result do you expect if multiple managers have equally the most employees? All of them? One of them? Which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any non-aggregate fields from the `SELECT` list must be included in the `GROUP BY`.  You can get what you want by using `LIMIT` or by using a window/analytic function:

```
select y.id, y.count as max_count 
FROM  (select m.manager_id as id
            , count(m.manager_id) as count 
       from employee m 
       GROUP BY id 
      ) y
order by count DESC
limit 1;
```

As pointed out in comments, even more straightforward:

```
select m.manager_id as id
     , count(m.manager_id) as count 
from employee m 
GROUP BY id 
order by count(m.manager_id) DESC
limit 1;
```

Comment: Interesting, so I can never get this working using MAX correct? BTW, the GROUP BY does include the id I am trying to display

Comment: @brainstorm The `GROUP BY` where you include `id` is inside the subquery,  but your outer query has another aggregate and therefore demands another `GROUP BY` if selecting non-aggregate fields.  You could get to the result using `MAX()` I just think this approach is more straight-forward.

Comment: is the derived table necessary? it seems that `group by id order by count(m.manager_id) desc limit 1` should do the trick

Comment: @GoatCO: I agree with your solution is more elegant. But it would be to nice to know how I could MAX to get the above working

Comment: @FuzzyTree: I am not very clear what you mean. please post as an answer if you can

Comment: @GoatCO: I would love to see (if it is possible) by using MAX though it might be complicated